# Changing SQL NOT IN to JOINS

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, notin

[image]

Hello guys,

Our aim is to get a script that will insert the missing pairs of product - TaxCategory in the intermediate table (ProductTaxCategory)

The following script is correctly working but we are trying to find a way to optimize it:

```
INSERT ProductTaxCategory
    (ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId,ProductTaxCategory_ProductId)
SELECT 
    TaxCategoryId
    ,ProductId 
FROM Product pr
CROSS JOIN TaxCategory tx
WHERE pr.ProductId NOT IN 
(
    SELECT ProductTaxCategory_ProductId
    FROM ProductTaxCategory
) 
OR
pr.ProductId IN 
(
    SELECT ProductTaxCategory_ProductId 
    FROM ProductTaxCategory
) 
AND
tx.TaxCategoryId NOT IN 
(
    SELECT ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId 
    FROM ProductTaxCategory 
    WHERE ProductTaxCategory_ProductId = pr.ProductId
 )
```

How can we optimize this query ?

Comment: MERGE may work better in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like (full statement now):

```
INSERT INTO ProductTaxCategory
    (ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId,ProductTaxCategory_ProductId)
SELECT TaxCategoryId, ProductId 
FROM Product pr CROSS JOIN TaxCategory tx
WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM ProductTaxCategory 
        WHERE ProductTaxCategory_ProductId     = pr.ProductId
        AND   ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId = tx.TaxCategoryId)
```

`EXISTS` with `(SELECT 1 ... WHERE ID=...)` is often a better alternative to `IN (SELECT ID FROM ... )` constructs.

Comment: Thanks! this took 160ms to execute compared to mine which took 1210ms

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` with `ProductTaxCategory`and check for `NULLs`.

Something like this.

```
INSERT ProductTaxCategory
(
    ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId,
    ProductTaxCategory_ProductId
)
SELECT p.TaxCategoryId, p.ProductId 
FROM 
(
    SELECT TaxCategoryId, ProductId
    FROM Product pr
    CROSS JOIN TaxCategory tx
) p
LEFT JOIN ProductTaxCategory ptx
    ON P.TaxCategoryId = ptx.ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId 
    AND P.ProductId = ptx.ProductTaxCategory_ProductId
WHERE ptx.ProductTaxCategory_ProductId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS JOIN` and `EXCEPT`

```
INSERT ProductTaxCategory(ProductTaxCategory_ProductId, ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId)

SELECT p.ProductID, tc.TaxCategoryId FROM Product p CROSS JOIN TaxCategory tc

EXCEPT

SELECT ProductTaxCategory_ProductId, ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId  FROM ProductTaxCategory
```

`CROSS JOIN` will search all the possible pairs. `EXCEPT` will get you what's missing. Finally you can `INSERT` them onto the table.

Comment: The OP has two different columns: `ProductTaxCategory_TaxCategoryId,
    ProductTaxCategory_ProductId`